# USB Wireless Keyboard with BT USB dongle in iOS

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

Does anybody tried to pair an iOS phone with any BLE USB dongle available in market which supports HID (Human interface devices) and can get the Key events to the target it is been connected from the iOS App.

We tried a similar concept in Android and are successful with the Android App with one of the BT smart dongle from Intelletto.
Now trying the same to be proved on iOS, can somebody give some insight if they have tried the same ?

Comment: There are no frameworks that will allow an iOS app to act as a legacy Bkuetooth HID device or HID over GATT BLE device.

Comment: @Paulw11, Appreciate for the prompt response...does that mean there is no possibility of this idea to be implemented on iOS, do you foresee any other connectivity (WiFi...etc) with iOS event triggering as HID?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  In theory you could use wifi or BLE to send commands to a helper app on a PC that then simulated keyboard events.

Comment: We are working on a project where we would like to pair a BT Phone (iOS) and create an App where we shall be sending some key events to Windows PC/Linux machine.
The BLE USB adapter should have the capability of collecting the iOS app touch events and converting them into HID events (Keyboard strokes) in the Linux machine where the USB dongle is connected to,this events once collected our SW in the target machine is capable of recognising this HID events and perform the operation of moving the HMI like traversing Up,Down,Right, Left, back.....so on.Hope you are clear now?.

Comment: You will need some application running on the Windows PC/Linux box for the iOS app to communicate with or you will need to find a BLE device that has a USB HID profile and write firmware inside the BLE device to communicate with the iOS app.

Comment: To be honest I'm trying to find both the options...but the second option we already developed an app working with Android using Intelletto Bluetooth keyboard emulator (using SPP profile into HID keys) but with iOS because of the framework and BT protocols support I could not find anything yet.Please suggest me if you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: For iOS you will probably need some custom hardware.